# Contact Form 7 : Add a class to <input> after clicking on Submit

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Form 7 on my WordPress, I had to remove all `span` elements automatically added by CF7 because it doesn't worked with bsCustomFileInput.

I'm looking for a way to add a class to `input` elements that have the class `verif-valid`, depending on the validity of the input.

My idea:

```js
$('.wpcf7-submit').on('click', function (e) {

For all input with class verif-valid :
  If is valid :
    Add class .is-valid
  Else :
    Add class .is-invalid

});
```

But I don't know how to write this, any ideas?

Comment: At the point that this logic runs, will the validity already have been determined?  If so, the logic is a simple usage of `hasClass()` and `addClass()`

Comment: The validity is determined by Contact Form 7 after clicking on "Submit". Without my code that remove automatic span added by CF7, we have a message displayed bellow each field that aren't validated. But I don't really understand how CF7 work so I don't know if I can retrieve these values to my code...

Comment: What I'm asking is, at the point that the click handler executes, will the inputs already have the `verif-valid` class on them?

Comment: Oh yes absolutely, because I don't want to add "is-valid" or "is-invalid" to fields that don't already have "verif-valid" class

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, you can just do `$('.verif-valid').addClass('whatever')` to put a class on all the element that have that class.

Comment: But I need to add my class "is-valid" to inputs that are validated by the plugin Contact Form 7, this is what I don't know how to do... For example, when all spans generated by CF7 are displayed in HTML (so without my code that remove them), when an input isn't validated, a message is showing in the span bellow the input. This is why I think I can retrieve this behaviour but in order to add a class instead of show a message

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('input').hasClass('verif-valid')){
   $('input').addClass('some-new-class');
}
```

to remove class

```
else{
  $('input').removeClass('some-old-class');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the function should add the class only if the input is invalidated by the plugin Contact Form 7 (if the field is required but empty for example)